# Python datetime - setting fixed hour and minute after using strptime to get day,month,year

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, date-manipulation

I've successfully converted something of `26 Sep 2012` format to `26-09-2012` using:

```
datetime.strptime(request.POST['sample_date'],'%d %b %Y')
```

However, I don't know how to set the hour and minute of something like the above to 11:59. Does anyone know how to do this?

Note, this can be a future date or any random one, not just the current date.

Answer (score 571):

Use [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('26 Sep 2012', '%d %b %Y')
newdatetime = dt.replace(hour=11, minute=59)
```

Also worth noting: `datetime.replace` returns a new copy of the `datetime` (since `datetime` is immutable): it is like `str.replace` in that regard.

Comment: Yes, just do `date = datetime.strptime('26 Sep 2012', '%d %b %Y').replace(hour=11, minute=59)`. I used the extra variable so that the line wasn't too long :)

Comment: Also worth noting: `datetime.replace` returns a new *copy* of the datetime (since `datetime` is immutable): it is like `str.replace` in that regard.

Comment: How can i remove everything after '2016-06-01' so that hour minute and second disappear?

Comment: @PV8 If you want a datetime, run: `r = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`. If you want a date object, run: `r = dt.date()`

Answer (score 68):

[datetime.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) will provide the best options. Also, it provides facility for replacing day, year, and month.

Suppose we have a `datetime` object and date is represented as: 
`"2017-05-04"`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime.strptime('2017-05-04',"%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print(date)
2017-05-04 00:00:00
>>> date = date.replace(minute=59, hour=23, second=59, year=2018, month=6, day=1)
>>> print(date)
2018-06-01 23:59:59
```

Comment: What's your answer's added value against nneonneo's answer posted 5 years before yours ?

Comment: @SamuelDauzon, I guess it added magic internet points value to his user account. And, tbh, it added the date elements but that could be an edit to nneonneo's answer.

Answer (score 18):

If you have a date as a `datetime.datetime` (or a `datetime.date`) instance and want to combine it via a time from a `datetime.time` instance, then you can use the classmethod [`datetime.datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```py
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 1)
t = datetime.time(12, 34)
combined = datetime.datetime.combine(dt.date(), t)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Shortcuts to convert datetime** to **max** [23:59:59.99] or **min** [0:00:00]

```
import datetime

def dt_time_min(dt):
    """converts any datetime/date to new datetime with same date and time=0:00:00"""
    return datetime.datetime.combine(dt, datetime.time.min)


def dt_time_max(dt):
    """converts any datetime/date to new datetime with same date and time=23:59:59.999999"""
    return datetime.datetime.combine(dt, datetime.time.max)
```