# Python Datetime strptime without year, automatically insert current year

Tags: python

I'm creating a function in python to parse date formats into a datetime object.
I want to automatically insert the current year if no year is set.

Here's my function:

```
from datetime import datetime


def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%d %m %y', '%d %m %Y', '%d.%m.%y', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d %B %y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %m', '%d. %m', '%d %B', '%d. %B'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt).date()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None
```

Comment: I suggest using an if-else condition to check to see if year is set

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You grab the current time, extract the year, and insert it into the date you're updating.

Comment: When there's no year set, it'll be automatically set to 1900, but I want it to be 2019.

Comment: @Xion how do I do that when I haven't parsed it to a datetime object? Can I check if there's an year set when I have a string?

Comment: @Myzel394: *"Can I check if there's an year set"*: Either checking `1900` in the result or `not '%y'|'%Y' in fmt`.

Comment: @stovfl I checked it and tried it but I can't change the year of a date attribute.

Comment: @Myzel394: Read about [datetime.datetime.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)

Comment: If `text` is a string and the date format is constant, then checking for year is easy. However, things get complex when the format is not the same. You should find a way to parse the string to a datetime object and then use the replace function as suggested.

Comment: @stovfl Note that use `.replace()` for the year may be dangerous, because 1900 does not have 2/29, while the target year may. ■ Somewhat related question: [python - How to parse string dates with 2-digit year? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600548/how-to-parse-string-dates-with-2-digit-year) [date - Python datetime - setting fixed hour and minute after using strptime to get day,month,year - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468823/python-datetime-setting-fixed-hour-and-minute-after-using-strptime-to-get-day)