# Adding current year to an inputed date

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I've written a fairly long script that organizes data and does some calculations etc, then saves that it all to another excel file in a different location. For the script to run the user enters a date in mmdd form so that it can find the text file with that name to open and run the calculations.

The issue I have comes in at the end when I want to enter the complete date in mm/dd/yy form in the first column of the excel file to keep in line with data from previous years that is already there.

Here is what I have:

```
mmdd = input("Enter txt file date in mmdd:")
#do a bunch of stuff to get new data
#get the date using mmdd
day = datetime.datetime.strptime(mmdd, '%m%d')
date = day.strftime('%m/%d')
#add data to excel file to new row without any data
row = ws.max_row + 1
new_row = [date, #all other data#]
```

When I run this it adds mm/dd to the first column no problem. However, I would like to add the *current year* to the end, i.e. mm/dd/19.

When I use this:

```
day = datetime.datetime.strptime(mmdd, '%m%d')
date = day.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

I obviously get a garbage year of 1900 because no year was specified in the first place.

I've also tried:

```
yr = datetime.datetime.now().year
```

But I can't get it to combine with mm/dd without throwing an error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468823/python-datetime-setting-fixed-hour-and-minute-after-using-strptime-to-get-day) answer your issue? replacing the year with `now().year`?

Comment: `data = datetime(year=datetime.now().year, month=int(mmdd[:2]), day=int(mmdd[2:]))`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tadhg, if you use the `.replace()` method together with `.now()`, you may get what you intend. Try this:

```
import datetime

day = datetime.datetime.strptime("1102", '%m%d')
date = day.replace(year=datetime.now().year)
print(date)
```

You'll get:

```
2019-11-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.