# Replace time portion of the Datatime in python with userdefined value

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a time string defined as below:

```
default = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I would like to replace the time portion alone with my defined time say 9:00:00

How would I be able accomplish this with datatime?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468823/python-datetime-setting-fixed-hour-and-minute-after-using-strptime-to-get-day

Answer (score 0):

Using Replace:

```
datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=23, minute=30).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```